# Snowflake network user-level policy

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to create network policies in snowflake with this design

1. A user called `loader` can access with some unique 5 IPs
2. A user called `transformer` can access with some other unique 5 IPs
3. All other users can access on any IP - i.e. no network policy

From the docs on snowflake and the approach, it seems I can only add an account-level policy, which is then used inside for users specifically as needed

Can I create directly user-level network policies **only** for 1, 2 and leave out 3 in some way?

Comment: Don't think of the network policy as being account-level.  You can just create 2 network policies and add them JUST to the users.  There is no need to add any of those policies to the account.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following page:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html#managing-user-level-network-policies

To activate a network policy for an individual user, set the NETWORK_POLICY parameter for the user using ALTER USER.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-network-policy

Comment: Thanks gokhan, but I don't see how exactly to set network_policy parameters exactly? They don't show up even when I check "show network policies;"  

How does snowflake enforce a policy only to a user level, if at the start we are creating an account level policy - I'd like to not get locked out too.

Comment: To see the parameters/allowed IPs, use the [`DESCRIBE NETWORK POLICY` command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-network-policy.html). Policies are not active upon creation; you need to active them yourself, either on the entire account or on specific users (the UI doesn't support activating them on users yet). Ex: `CREATE NETWORK POLICY pol ALLOWED_IP_LIST=('1.2.3.4');`, then `ALTER ACCOUNT SET NETWORK_POLICY = pol;` or `ALTER USER john SET NETWORK_POLICY = pol;`